# Windows 8 Video / Audio Not in Sync

Tags: windows-8, nvidia-graphics-card

My windows 8 videos plays the video about 200ms before the audio.
This happens for saved videos as well as youtube videos.

What I have tried.

- Removed my graphics card.
- Update all drivers.
- Used different media players.
- Format with windows 8 again.

Hardware: Asus p8z77-v mobo with realtek on-board sound,
Nvidia 680 Gigabyte OC Edition,
8GB Kingston 1600 Ram

Comment: This sounds like either a pure hardware issue or a driver issue if it happens on a fresh install.  Contact Asus for support in either case.

Comment: I tested this using my hard drive in my friends PC with basically the same specs and same motherboard. The same thing happened. After that I installed windows 7 on a different drive and same thing.

Comment: **Have you contacted ASUS for support since this appears to be a driver issue?**  The fact this happens for both `Windows 7` and `Windows 8` indicates to me that the audio device does not support either operating system.